# ASM code in C program causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I included some sample ASM code in a small program to do a test.

My program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline
unsigned char inb (int port) {
    unsigned char data;
    asm volatile("inb %w1,%0" : "=a" (data) : "d" (port));
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    printf("hello world %d\n", inb(22));
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it crashes with a segmentation fault when executing the ASM code.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with this small program? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OS is Windows or Linux, most likely your program is terminated because the OS doesn't allow regular applications access I/O ports.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`ioperm`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioperm.2.html) before you're allowed to use port I/O. Also, note the kernel already provides [`inb` and `outb` functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/outb.2.html).

> Use ioperm(2) or alternatively iopl(2) to tell the kernel to allow the
>   user space application to access the I/O ports in question.  Failure
>   to do this will cause the application to receive a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You syntax is absolutely correct. Just find and use the valid or unused port on your system.